# Text shadow behavior in iOS5

Tags: ios5, css

I currently develop a website in mobile safari. I am stuck on a problem that the text shadow behavior in iOS5 and iOS4 is completely different such as the blue effect. And the result of text shadow position is also different between iPhone 3G (non-retina) with iOS5 and iPhone 4 (retina) with iOS5. CSS code is "text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ffffff". Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: There's probably nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Maybe a little late but do you use this meta setting?

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">

This effects the text-shadow position in a way it didn't do before. I'm having this problem but haven't figured out a way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As thirtydot suggested, there is nothing you can do about this. This is the way safari renders your html and css.

The only thing you could and should do is file a bug to apple. Go to http://developer.apple.com and check where to file a bug about this.

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across this - I had an App rejected from Apple due to the difference with the way Io5 displays text-shadows. Text shadows which previously looked fine now appear to display badly in Io5, creating blurry textm and as a result the app failed Apples Human Interface Guidelines.

It would appear to suggest that text shadows, at least ones on dark text on a light background, can no longer be used on iPhone apps.